# fsockopen on SSL does not working on specific host

Tags: php, ssl, fsockopen

On working production server, at some point (June 24 at 13:18), fsockopen started to fail with no seen reason.

```
$sock = fsockopen("ssl://mail.dupcheck.org",993, $errno, $errstr, 300);
```

- it returns: $sock = false, errno = 0, errstr = "" quite fast.
- it opens other servers.

Important to mention,

- it does not work both, on linux web server and on windows (WAMP) development server
- MS Outlook and other mail clients perfectly connect to this server and fetch the mail.
- that day (June 24) we had some issues with GoDaddy SSL certificate - it started to show improper date! We called GoDaddy's support then and they say,  the issue is fixed.
- Since then, for almost a month, SOMETIMES fsockopen worked and we received emails, and nobody paid attention, nobody checked that specific mailsend log ... until today it reached 300M!

====

PHP 7.3.3-1, ubuntu16.04.1

---

Yes, I read manuals, googled for several hours, no relief. Nobody knows what's that, including system administrators.

Comment: Maybe elaborate on "it started to show improper date"... How does that occur? Assuming issue is not server side, then the old adage of "what changed" is useful. OpenSSL changes? CA Bundle expired (a lack of change)?  No warnings in the logs tied to that `fsockopen` call? Issue is intermittent?

Comment: https://tls.imirhil.fr/tls/mail.dupcheck.org:993 does not seem to show anything extraordinary. You should increase your logging, and try to reproduce the problem at the same time outside of PHP. As it stands your question is not really programming related, so [su] or [sf] may be better venues.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek, I just cannot increase logging more:
The problem occurs only on the mentioned line, and shows no errors or anything suspicious, except for no socket created.
Yes, it looks as not strictly  programming related, except for fsockopen, in the end, is.

Comment: @ficuscr, cron calls the mailsend function every 1 minute.... and mail logs just filled with literally zillion messages (since June 24) with 'fsockopen cannot open socket due to errstr="", errno=0, socket-false'.
We failed to understand what happened with weird SSL certificate behavior. Just re-installed a proper one.
Looks as the issue is somehow related to SSL certificate, but nobody, really nobody, was able to elaborate more on this.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic just using `fsockopen` does not automatically mean your question fits in any of the 4 bullets described there.

Comment: "I just cannot increase logging more" Why? When the problem occurs, do you reproduce it with say `openssl s_client` or any other TLS client? Can you sniff the network and see what is exchanged? Did you try same code from another host? Another PHP/OpenSSL version? Etc.

Comment: Also from documentation: "If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE, it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call. This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket. " Which would mean it is not a TLS problem at all. Maybe you have DNS resolution problems or you hit some limits on the number of sockets that your program can have open at any given time. This should be written somewhere in some logfiles, if they are verbose enough.

Comment: Yes, @PatrickMevzek, tried different hosts, `openssl s_client` perfectly working, socket creating too.
Did not try with different PHP/OpenSSL. (it is PHP7.3 dependent), so "This is most likely due to a problem initializing the socket." does not scratch my back

Comment: And yes, nothing in logs except for warning (with error_reporting(-1))
fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://mail.dupcheck.org:993 (Unknown error) in ...

Comment: Catch the error when it happens, then try directly `socket_create` and `socket_connect` and catch errors there, and use `socket_last_error()`. Use a loop. When the problem happens, it stays or go away after "some time"? (your "SOMETIMES" in question is worrisome, please be clearer on the frequency/duration of the problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment:

> ... openssl s_client perfectly working ...

It works in that it connects and does a TLS handshake. But it does not work perfectly since it clearly shows that the certificate validation fails:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.dupcheck.org:993
...
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=mail.dupcheck.org
   i:/C=US/ST=Arizona/L=Scottsdale/O=GoDaddy.com, Inc./OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository//CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
...
    Verify return code: 10 (certificate has expired)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Taking a closer look at the certificate:

```
    Serial Number:
        92:a0:2d:2a:2f:28:6a:d5
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
    Validity
        Not Before: Jun 24 10:16:38 2016 GMT
        Not After : Jun 24 10:16:38 2019 GMT
```

Thus, this certificate was expired some weeks ago. This is likely the reason the connection fails.

> ... 
>   tls.imirhil.fr/tls/mail.dupcheck.org:993 does not seem to show anything extraordinary.

It looks like this site does not check the validity of the certificate at all.

Comment: (it still does not answer HOW this might happen, since exactly this error we had out of blue at Jun 24, despite the certificate was up to 2023... so reinstalled)

Comment: @AlexeyAbraham: The installation of the certificate has nothing to do with this code but is related to the setup of the server. Nothing is known about this setup and how  things got messed up there and who or what might have done it.

Comment: It WAS some issue with GoDaddy's certificates in June - several expired before the real expiration date. But indeed. You have almost the same knowledge about the certificate installation as I :)